# How to generate pdf reports in python 3.2.3?

Tags: python, django, pdf, python-3.2, django-1.6

I am trying to export the reports which is generated using **python 3.2.3** & **django 1.6** to pdf.
I swicthed to python3.2.3 now only,earlier I was using python2.7 in which I used **PISA** for pdf generation. bt **PISA** is not available in python3.2.3

Can anybody suggest me how to generate pdf in python 3.2.3

Comment: on a side note why did you switch to python 3.2.3 and not the latest?

Comment: I installed it using "synaptic package manager" (Ububntu 12.04).  In which python 3.2.3 was the latest version

Comment: python 3.4 is the latest on ubuntu

Comment: okay... Is there any package for pdf generation in python 3.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to generate PDFs from HTML, you can use weasyprint, which supports python 3, and has really cool capabilities.
http://weasyprint.org/

You can also use wkhtmltopdf (based on webkit). It's a command line tool, but there is a python pdfkit wrapper for it. I really like wkhtmltopdf as in some cases it's much faster than PISA or weasyprint.

They both handle CSS, so the styling is pretty easy and powerful.